Astronaut stranded outside spacecraft
There was a sci-fi movie I recall seeing on British TV around 10-15 years ago and I can't remember the title. I believe the movie was quite recent at the time and made in the US.
The main things I remember about the movie are:

The premise was similar to that to Alien in that a handful of
passengers, in the near future, are travelling on a large space-craft
I think in the outer reaches of the solar system.
The main plot event I remember is that towards the end, as the movie is nearing its conclusion, a number of the astronauts are outside of the spacecraft wearing space-suits. They are completely detatched from the spacecraft and propel themselves using small rocket thrusters that are built into the space suit. One protagontist is running out of fuel but nevertheless pursues her objective regardless. She eventually runs out of fuel and is left floating in space with no other means of propulsion, with her objective, some sort of ladder(?), just inches out of reach. Due to Newton's laws, with no means of propulsion in the vacuum of space, she is doomed to remain in the same spot indefinitely, infuriatingly close to the ladder.

Is there anyone that recognises this movie and, if so, can they remember the title?
I really hope this is a real movie and not just some weird dream I am mis-remembering. :-)

Newton's Law would dictate that, after running out of fuel, she wouldn't stop, but would continue, indefinitely at the same velocity in the same direction, unless some other force acted upon her.

@PoloHoleSet Thanks for the response - one for physics.stackexchange.com maybe. Do you know the title of the movie?

You sure it was a woman who got stranded?

What you describe loosely sounds like a scene from Mission to Mars (2000) where the astronauts had to leave the ship due to an explosion and try to reach another orbiting module; however, this was between the middle and last-half of the movie, but not at the end.

@TurboPT Hence my question since it was a man who got stranded in MTM

@Paulie_D:  Yes, I saw that ... I left that detail out of my comment since you brought it up. No worries! :-)

@steviejay - Not sure of the movie.  Like with others, it reminds me of Mission To Mars, but the specifics of the details diverge a bit from that one.

This movie is called Mission To Mars. Thanks to @Paulie_D and @TurboPT for their responses. I've just seen the a clip of the scene I described in my original question. The stranded astronaut's wife attempts to save him - I think this is why my memory has confused the gender of the astronaut. Also, @TurboPT is correct in that this scene occurs in the middle of the movie not the end. 
